# Installed ubuntu after installing rEFInd, and my Macbook only boots to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, macintosh, apple, refind

I am an electrical engineering student, and I use a late 2016 macbook pro with the touch bar. I partitioned my drive, so I could install multiple OSs on my drive. I plan on having a(n existing) macOS partition, a ubuntu partition, and a windows 10 partition.

I installed rEFInd, which went well. Whenever I booted, rEFInd would come up, and I could select to boot the macOS portion, or to boot from the Ubuntu installation drive. I booted to the installation drive, and successfully installed ubuntu to one of the partitions on my drive.

**Now that I have installed Ubuntu, rEFInd no longer comes up, my computer boots straight to Ubuntu. How can I make my computer boot back to the existing rEFInd?**

I am able to boot to macOS recovery by using [command] + R. I am also able to boot to my standard macOS partition by holding [option] while the computer boots, which lets me choose the boot drive.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`?

Comment: If you can boot back into the MacOS, you can reinstall rEFInd from there.  That is how I did it on my Macbook Pro.